# Atribuir o retorno de uma função que retorna de uma Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async, promises, webpack

Estou exportando uma função para outro arquivo que está como um componente Webpack-simple + VueJS. Essa é a função do arquivo *api-user.js*:

```
export function getUsers () {
    axios.post('/api/get_list',{})
    .then(req => {return req.data.list;})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

No arquivo *myComponent.vue*, estou importando ela e chamando assim:

```
created: async function () {
      this.arrayUsers = await getUsers()
      console.log(this.arrayUsers)

},
```

porém apenas recebo `undefined`, e não estou entendendo muito bem o porque.

Um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer:

https://codesandbox.io/s/n046mxwpm

---

## EDIT:

Consegui de uma maneira aqui, mas não é o que desejo ainda, pois requer muito código no arquivo qual estou tentando manter mais limpo.

**api-user.js:**

```
export function getUsers () { 
    return axios.post('/apiminer/get_list',{}) 
}
```

**mycomponent.vue:**

```
created: function() { 

    getUsers().then((res) => { 
         this.arrayUsers= res.data.list 
    }) 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei te dizer exatamente o erro que pode estar acontecendo, mas tentarei ajudar com base no que você informou.

O primeiro erro que vejo, é que você possui um método `getUsers()`, porém dentro do método você está realizando um `post`, no caso `axios.post`. Neste caso era para ocorrer mais erros, como, por exemplo, 405 - *Method not Allowed*, com exceção de retornar `undefined.`

Outro problema que pode acontecer, é que no Vuejs, eu particularmente importo funções assim de outros arquivos para utilizá-las como [filters](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html), diretamente em sua tag `<template>`, e não para chamar funções dentro do `created()`.

Posso sugerir para você tentar trocar esta função para ser utilizada como um mixin, e assim pode ser que ajude a resolver o problema. Veja abaixo:

**api-users.js**

```
export default {
  methods: {
    getUsers () {
      axios.post('/api/get_list',{})
        .then(req => {return req.data.list;})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
  }
}
```

**myComponent.vue**

Em seu `<template>`, insira:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in arrayUsers" v-if="arrayUsers && arrayUsers.length">
```

Abaixo é o código dentro do `<script>`:

```
import apiUser from "./api-user.js";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  mixins: [apiUser],
  data() {
    return {
      arrayUsers: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.arrayUsers = this.getUsers();
  },      
};
```

**Observações:**

1. Corrija o diretório da importação do *mixin* `apiUsers`;
2. Verifique se sua configuração em seu `main.js` ou outro arquivo de configuração, como a porta, etc, está correto;
3. Verifique se nome do método no back-end está correto, bem como seu tipo e o retorno da api, se de fato está sendo retornado em um array de objetos `list`, dentro do data. Realize algum tipo de teste automatizado ou teste-o pelo *Postman*.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A api está ok, já testei. Não entendi porque era para ocorrer "405 - Method not Allowed", pois se faço o mesmo no arquivo do componente tudo funciona, o problema está ao tentar organizar o código em dois arquivos separados. Já tentei com mixins e não funcionou. O problema que eu vejo(não tenho certeza) é que estou retornando de um método que tem uma promisse, e como é assincrono, não tem muita certeza quando irá atribuir o valor a variável arrayUsers, o que pode acontecer de receber undefined, porém o vuejs é reativo, então creio que não seja isso, já não tenho mais ideia do que tentar.

Comment: Apenas para comentar, por algum motivo minha internet não quer abrir o link enviado no codesandbox. Se estiver passando informações que não ajudam, me informe que deleto a resposta.

Comment: abri aqui em outro computador e foi, testa ai novamente o link.

Comment: @PerduGames Tentou exatamente com o código que passei e não funcionou? Estranho mesmo. Sobre o 405, geralmente em API's rest, no back-end para trazer dados, no caso usuários, é definido que será realizado um GET. Logo, em seu front-end deve ser feito um GET, caso contrário usualmente voltará o 405. No caso de ser asíncrono ou não, no momento que ele receber o retorno ele irá atribuir o retorno a sua variável data.

Comment: Não é isso, com a API está tudo ok, no exemplo do codesandbox utilizo chamando por get, mas essa interna aqui é post mesmo, mas está ok, tudo testado já. O problema está em algum conceito ai do javascript ou vuejs que ainda não entendo. E tentei sim, na verdade foi a primeira tentativa que fiz foi com mixins.

Comment: Verifiquei pelo celular a postagem e editei a resposta, veja se ajuda em algo. Apesar de que está um pouco diferente o código do codesandbox pelo que vi.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74708/discussion-between-guastallaigor-and-perdugames).

Answer (score 0):

O método da API retorna uma *promise* e você tá retornando essa *promise* pra dentro da função `getUsers()`.

A função `getUsers()` também deve retornar uma *promise* ficando assim:

```
getUsers(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    api.post(url).then(({ data }) => resolve(data))
  });
}
```